# Why does "Successful transactions"+"Failed transactions" != "Transactions"

Tags: siege

Using the siege load testing tool, it sends a number of transactions to a server.

The output is typically something like:

```
** SIEGE 4.0.4
** Preparing 1 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
Transactions:                 10 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:              14.31 secs
Data transferred:           0.09 MB
Response time:              1.43 secs
Transaction rate:           0.70 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.01 MB/sec
Concurrency:                1.00
Successful transactions:          10
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            4.54
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Sometimes in testing I see that the number of successful transactions plus the number of failed transactions does not equal the total number of transactions (e.g. 1000 transactions, 992 successful, 4 failed). Sometimes the total is lower, sometimes the total is higher (e.g. 1000 transactions, 998 success, 4 fail). What does this mean? What happened to these non-success and non-fail transactions?